# Trapping All Batch Job from MVS

Tags: batch-processing, mvs

I'm trying to trap all the batch Job from MVS.
I want to transmit all the batch job information (start,end,error) to an external system in order to conduct further analysis.
Has anyone got any idea on how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Write an IEFACTRT exit (or whatever its modern day equivalent is) and have the systems programmers install it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But IEFACTRT is not use only to know the termination of a job ? In my case I would as well trap what is started but not ended.

Comment: There are a number of exits. See http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r13/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r13.ieae400%2Fiea2e4c0131.htm to identify which might be helpful to you. Do you really need the data real-time?  If not it is much easier to read SMF data later (which would be the case for 'further analysis').

Answer (score 0):

IBM actually provides a facility for this.  You can have it write SMF (System Management Facility) records for all jobs.  The record layouts are available and you can write code to do analysis on them or you can get 3rd party products like OmegaMon that will do the analysis and reporting for you.

Answer (score 0):

as in my shop, we print the job info into plain files, and ftp down to some file servers and from where we run extract/format with some scripts and pull the data into BI platform for later analysis/visualisation. 
Currently, we are studying to utilise the power of graph db like Neo4j to deeper understand our batch job relationship/better present the job relationship with people who interested. and for now we think graph db is a very neat tool for such kind of thing(batch job management)...
Hope my answer can give you some inspiration/reminders...

Answer (score 0):

Typically, installations cut **SMF type 30** records.  **Subtype 1** is written when a new transaction is started.  `transaction` means, *System Resources Manager* (SRM) transaction. Don't confuse it with transactions in the context of e.g. a database system.  A batch job that begins execution is such a transaction.  **Subtype 5** is written when a transaction ends.  Along with subtype 5, there is a completion section that reports the job termination status.

Now, SMF processing is traditionally done in batch as you have to prepare the SMF records first either by extracting them from the log stream or from one of the SYS1.MANx data sets.

But recently, capabilities have been added to z/OS that allow you to hook into the process when SMF records are written.  A product like the IBM Common Data Provider for z/OS can be used transform the data in the way you want it to be and to stream it to a destination of choice, for instance logstash.  Following such a technique allows to process SMF records almost in real time.